# I need user information by search keyword

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

> By this the search script. visitor will get the user information using the nicename. this script working perfectly. But i need more
> information for each user. like First name, Last name, phone number,
> email address. How to write the script? Any one can help me.
>
> ```
> <form action="/custom-search" method="GET">
>
> <div class="search boxes">   
> <input type="text" name="ven_search_title" class="customsearch-field" placeholder="Vendor Search"> 
> <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
> </div>
>
> </form>
>
> <?php
>
>  if (sanitize_text_field($_GET['ven_search_title']) && sanitize_text_field ($_GET['ven_search_title']))
>     {
>       $ven_search_title = sanitize_text_field($_GET['ven_search_title']);
>     }
>     
>     global $wpdb;
>     $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
>     $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename FROM $table WHERE user_nicename LIKE '".$ven_search_title."'", ARRAY_A);
>   
>     foreach ($query as $value) {
>          echo $value['user_nicename'];
>      }
>
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get user information by using this function: [get_user_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/)

Try out the below solution and let me know if it works for you or not.

```
<?php
$user_nicename = sanitize_text_field($_GET['ven_search_title']);
$user = get_user_by('slug', $user_nicename);

if ($user) {
    // user found, get the user information
    $user_first_name = $user->first_name;
    $user_last_name = $user->last_name;
    $user_login = $user->user_login;
    $user_email = $user->user_email;
    $user_display_name = $user->display_name;

    // do something with the user information
    echo "User First Name: " . $user_first_name . "<br>";
    echo "User Last Name: " . $user_last_name . "<br>";
    echo "User Login: " . $user_login . "<br>";
    echo "User Email: " . $user_email . "<br>";
    echo "User Display Name: " . $user_display_name . "<br>";
} else {
    // user not found
    echo "User not found.";
}
?>
```

You can get more information by using the [get_user_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) function. If you need another information checkout the documentation of the function.